# Month and java.util.Formatter

Tags: java, date, calendar

In the [javadoc of java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) I read:

> 'm'   Month, formatted as two digits with leading zeros as necessary,
>   i.e. 01 - 13.

Why 13?

Comment: See also [UNDECIMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#UNDECIMBER)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javadoc explains why..

> 'm'    '\u006d'     Month, formatted as two digits with leading zeros as necessary, i.e. 01 - 13, where "01" is the first month of the year and **("13" is a special value required to support lunar calendars).**

Comment: Damn... it is huge, the month is described at two places one without the lunar thing which is available in the Details section. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah! it is defined at two places..:)